# href="#" is breaking Angular route

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

So I have a route setup as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("MSL", [])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when("/dev.html", {
            redirectTo: "/template1"
        })
        .when("/template1", {
            templateUrl: "/views/template1.html",
            controller: "template1Ctlr"
        })

});
```

Because of internal reason I can't use the html5mode. I'm also using Foudation for this project as it's a demo. I have a form which uses the Foudation custom form styles. This means that the dropdowns are replaced (dynamically) with regular div/a/ul elements to acheive the styling. THis is all good, except for the fact that the dropdown is now an a tag with an href="#". Since I'm not using html5 mode the url is as follows:

```
/dev.html#/template1
```

When I click on the dropdown (a tag) I'm redirected to

```
/dev.html
```

because of the href. Is there a way around this? I don't want to have to modify the Foundation files (which I shouldn't have to).

As always thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can't you just remove the `"#"` from `href="#"` altogether?

Comment: @Stewie I could but I would have to modify the Foundation JavaScript files to do so, which I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using jQuery to dynamically change the url as follows:

```
$(".dropdown a").attr("href", location.hash + "#");
```

This will turn the href my dropdown links to

```
/dev.html#/template1#
```

which works fine.